# How to force the display of an empty field in panels for an editable field?

Tags: entities, panels

I can't seem to force an empty field to display so that it can be edited with editable fields. I installed the [Empty fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_fields) module which adds an option in the pane settings but still no luck.

Has anyone had success with this?

Edit: *Form content* with added submit buttons work, but *Page Content* is far more user friendly.

Comment: In empty display options, did you type something for the custom value?

Comment: Yep.. If I set a value and then delete it, that custom value displays until a page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

In your `/sites/all/theme/YourTheme/template.php` file, you could try using

```
function YourThemeName_preprocess_content_field(&$variables) {

    if (!isset($variables['field_name']) {
    $variables['field_name'] = ' ';
  }
}
```

but I don't know if the empty `' '` will show.

Comment: I went for an editable view pane which let me put a few fields in one pane.. Works fine. Good advice though.